# jsの変数の中身について

Tags: javascript

***状況***
google chromeのデベロッパーツール内のコンソール機能で簡単なコードを打ち込んで変数のスコープについて調べていました。
その中で1つだけ理由が分からない結果があったので理屈が知りたいので質問します。

***コード***

```js
 {
  // 親で宣言した変数
  var a = 10
  function hoge() {
      // 今のaの状態を表示。親で初期化されてるため10が表示される
     console.log('hoge', a)
     // 親の値を書き換える
    var  a = 20
  }
  hoge()
  // ここはhogeで書きかわっているので、20が表示される
  console.log('fuga', a)
}
```

↑↑このhoge関数内の `var a=20` の`var`が無ければ`hoge 10`と表示されるのですが,なぜか`var`をつけると`undefined`になってしまいます。
スコープやクロージャの概念があまり理解できていないので初歩的な質問をしてしまいたしたが、回答していただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScriptで最も奇妙な仕様ですね。**`var` で宣言された変数のスコープは、宣言した場所に関わらず関数全体**になります。

質問文のコードは、以下と同じ挙動になります。

```js
function hoge() {
  var a;
  console.log('hoge', a); // ローカルの a を参照
  a = 20;
}
```

Comment: 「javascript 巻き上げ」と呼ばれる現象ですね

Comment: ありがとうございました！関数内でvarを宣言、初期化する際は先頭部でするように気を付けます。